# Filtering tomcat log using awk/perl

Tags: perl, tomcat, logging, awk, filtering

I am trying to extract error|exception from tomcat log. Since tomcat logs have error details in multiple lines. I would like to consider every new log entry as my record i.e. date may act as a Record separator.

`Oct 4, 2012 4:00:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1531)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        at com.myweb.ontest.stats.RpcInterceptor.intercept(RpcInterceptor.java:45)
        at com.myweb.ontest.platform.SupplySource$Iface$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b5e8142.finalize()
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:83)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:14)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:160)
Oct 4, 2012 4:00:38 PM Org.apache.catalina.loader ....`

Please let me know how it can be done using awk/perl script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd first add a blank line between records with:

```
awk '/^[A-Z][a-z]/ && f++{print ""}1' file
```

so you can easily process it in a subsequent awk script by using a blank line as the record-separator:

```
awk '/^[A-Z][a-z]/ && f++{print ""}1' file |
awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{print "Record #" NR; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "Field #" i, "[" $i "]"}'
Record #1
Field #1 [Oct 4, 2012 4:00:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass]
Field #2 [INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.]
Field #3 [java.lang.IllegalStateException]
Field #4 [        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1531)]
Field #5 [        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)]
Field #6 [        at com.myweb.ontest.stats.RpcInterceptor.intercept(RpcInterceptor.java:45)]
Field #7 [        at com.myweb.ontest.platform.SupplySource$Iface$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b5e8142.finalize()]
Field #8 [        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)]
Field #9 [        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:83)]
Field #10 [        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:14)]
Field #11 [        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:160)]
Record #2
Field #1 [Oct 7, 2012 4:00:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass]
Field #2 [INFO: just a dummy record]
Field #3 [java.lang.IllegalStateException]
Field #4 [        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1531)]
Field #5 [        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)]
Field #6 [        at com.myweb.ontest.stats.RpcInterceptor.intercept(RpcInterceptor.java:45)]
Field #7 [        at com.myweb.ontest.platform.SupplySource$Iface$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b5e8142.finalize()]
Field #8 [        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)]
Field #9 [        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:83)]
Field #10 [        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:14)]
Field #11 [        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:160)]
```

You didn't post what you wanted your output to look like so if the above doesn't give you enough info to do that, post the expected output for your sample input

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are going to put those errors in a MySQL database I would do it like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw( -no_match_vars $OS_ERROR );
use Readonly;
use DBI;

Readonly my $LOG_FILENAME => '/var/log/tomcat.log';

Readonly my $DATE_REGEX => qr{
    \w{3} \s \d+, \s        # Oct 4,
    \d{4}         \s        # 2012
    \d+:\d+:\d+   \s \w{2}  # 4:00:38 PM
}xms;

my $sth;
{
    my $dbh = DBI->connect(
        'DBI:mysql:database=errors;host=localhost',
        'error_monitor',
        '*********',
        { 'RaiseError' => 1 }
    );

    die $DBI::errstr
        if !$dbh;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached( q{
        INSERT INTO error (
            date,
            text
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            ?
        )
    } );

    die $DBI::errstr
        if !$sth;
}

my $fh;
{
    open $fh, '<', $LOG_FILENAME
        or die "open $LOG_FILENAME: $OS_ERROR";
}

my ( $count, %record ) = ( 0, () );

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

    if ( $line =~ m{\A ( $DATE_REGEX ) \s ( .+ ) }xms ) {

        my ( $date, $text ) = ( $1, $2 );

        if (%record) {
            $sth->execute( @record{qw( date text )} );
            %record = ();
            $count++;
        }

        @record{qw( date text )} = ( $date, $text );
    }
    elsif ( exists $record{date} ) {

        $record{text} .= $line;
    }
    else {

        warn "malformed message: $line";
    }
}

if (%record) {
    $sth->execute( @record{qw( date text )} );
    $count++;
}

close $fh
    or die "close $LOG_FILENAME: $OS_ERROR";

print "inserted $count error records\n"
    or die "print: $OS_ERROR";

__END__
```

Answer (score 0):

And in perl you could do it like this :-

```
use strict;
my $log = join('', <STDIN>);
my %entries = split(/([\r\n]*\w{3} \d+, \d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ [AP]M )/m, $log);

foreach my $key(keys %entries)
{
    print "$key\n";
    print "$entries{$key}\n";
}
```

The code above reads the entire log from stdin, splits it on dates and stores the date, entry into a hash and prints the hash in the end.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for providing me a key to extract error|exception from log.